# how to suppress the NA replacement when converting to numerical?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

let's say I have the following data:

```
dput(mydata)
structure(list(a = c("20", "30", "25", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
".", "25", "0", "1"), b = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1), c = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3), d = c(5, 2, 3, 
1, 3, 13, 1, 3, 1, 31, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then, I want to apply a code converting all columns from character to numerical.

```
mydata_convert <- mydata %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
```

The problem is that the all the "." values had been replaced by NAs.

> Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion

Could you please advice on how to retain the original values (so that these values not to be confused with the already existing NAs), and suppress the NA replacement when apply this code please:

```
mydata_convert <- mydata %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are those values `0.0`? What number do they represent?

Comment: thanks Rui for your question, no these are not real numerical values. These are just values that represent cases where the experiment malfunctioned.

Comment: If R would read them as "0", do you recommend I name them something else first? Thanks again fro your help Rui.

Comment: Thanks Darren for your feedback. I guess I would need to recede them as negative values then. So sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If those values represent cases where the experiment malfunctioned, I suggest you store them as `NA`, it's better than negative values that might become part of further calculations. Special values, such as negative numbers, would force you to have special code to process them every time you need it.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot for your help Rui.

Answer (score 3):

The following code first substitutes `"0.0"` for the single dot `"."` then coerces to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, list(function(x) sub("^\\.$", "0.0", x))) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
#    a b c  d
#1  20 1 1  5
#2  30 1 2  2
#3  25 1 3  3
#4   0 0 5  1
#5   0 0 2  3
#6   0 0 1 13
#7   0 0 2  1
#8   0 0 3  3
#9   0 0 1  1
#10 25 1 3 31
#11  0 1 1  2
#12  1 1 3  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ifelse`:

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, ~ ifelse(. == ".", 0, .) %>% as.numeric)

#      a b c  d
#  1  20 1 1  5
#  2  30 1 2  2
#  3  25 1 3  3
#  4   0 0 5  1
#  5   0 0 2  3
#  6   0 0 1 13
#  7   0 0 2  1
#  8   0 0 3  3
#  9   0 0 1  1
#  10 25 1 3 31
#  11  0 1 1  2
#  12  1 1 3  1
```

Comment: Many thanks Darren for your help on this, but could you please advise if there is a way I keep the original coding of "." and not convert it to "0" while transforming to numerical.